# weblogic-maven-plugin 2.9.1

Tags: java, maven-plugin, maven-3, weblogic-10.x, maven-ant-tasks

Trying to execute jwsc task using weblogi-maven-plugin getting below errors

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>weblogic-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>compile</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>jwsc</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <contextPath>${basedir}/AccountInqWeb</contextPath>
                        <weblogicHome>C:/u001/isuser/tesbea</weblogicHome>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:weblogic-maven-plugin:2.9.1:jwsc (default) on project AccountInqWeb: Execution default of goal org.codehaus.mojo:weblogic-maven-plugin:2.9.1:jwsc failed: A required class was missing while executing org.codehaus.mojo:weblogic-maven-plugin:2.9.1:jwsc: weblogic/diagnostics/debug/DebugLogger

---

realm =    plugin>org.codehaus.mojo:weblogic-maven-plugin:2.9.1
 strategy = org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy
 urls[0] = file:/C:/Users/darshanp/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/mojo/weblogic-maven-plugin/2.9.1/weblogic-maven-plugin-2.9.1.jar
 urls[1] = file:/C:/Users/darshanp/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/1.0.4/plexus-utils-1.0.4.jar
 urls[2] = file:/C:/Users/darshanp/.m2/repository/ant/ant/1.6.5/ant-1.6.5.jar
 urls[3] = file:/C:/Users/darshanp/.m2/repository/weblogic/weblogic/10.3/weblogic-10.3.jar
 urls[4] = file:/C:/Users/darshanp/.m2/repository/weblogic/webservices/10.3/webservices-10.3.jar
 Number of foreign imports: 1
 import: Entry[import  from realm ClassRealm[maven.api, parent: null]]

-----------------------------------------------------: weblogic.diagnostics.debug.DebugLogger
 -> [Help 1]

Answer (score 0):

First you must enter the code as the dependence you have there. But there is a major mistake that you must not have noticed, dependedo version of weblogic in this case the 10 to 12c to the org.codehaus.mojo can not do with weblogic deployment. For that you have to go by cmd / terminal until your "**wlserver_12.1 \ server \ lib**" and do seguinto command:

-**java-jar-profile wljarbuilder.jar weblogic-maven-plugin**

This plugin has all the settings so you can use the Weblogic 100%

Second if that does not work and you're in IDE netbeans tries to do the following command, right click in the dependencies and after the doings Download Declared Dependency.